# How to execute same test cases with different test property sources

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test

I am building a cloud agnostic spring boot application that has separate cloud provider bean for different cloud providers. These beans are initialised based on the value of a configuration called `cloud.provider` having possible values `aws`, `ocp`, `azure` & `gcp`

There is only one class containing test cases that I would like to execute separately for all cloud providers

I have the following structure of classes:

```
interface CloudProvider {
  String process(String input);
}
```

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "cloud.provider", havingValue = "aws")
class AwsProvider implements CloudProvider {
  String process(String input) {
    //process and return aws specific key
  }
}
```

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "cloud.provider", havingValue = "gcp")
class GcpProvider implements CloudProvider {
  String process(String input) {
    //process and return gcp specific key
  }
}
```

For which the test cases look something like:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"mtls.provider=aws"})
class CloudProviderIT {

  @Autowired
  private CloudProvider provider;

  void testProcessForCloudProviders() {
    provider.process("input-string");
    //Then do some business specific assertions
  }
}
```

The test case remains same for all cloud providers and I don't want to create a new test class for each cloud provider to force recreation of spring context.

Is there a way I could paremeterize @SpringBootTest such that the same class executes but each time with a value from all possible values

Comment: you can use @ParameterizedTest

Comment: I could parameterise the test methods but not the context creation at the test class level. Wouldn't work!

Comment: Are you trying to suggest that I create the whole application context for each test method?

Could you elaborate with an example here please..

Comment: Sorry, my bad :) , I missed @ConditionalOnProperty. This won't work

Comment: I think It would have been easier if you had some Factory class to return Cloud Provider instead of creating bean based on cloud.provider value.

Comment: I agree but I just don't wanna change my code straight away cause there isn't an out of the box way to test it easily